# Filter Duplicates in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am playing with tableau dashboard, I have below data.
[image].

so I have 2 users for Facebook, 2 users for Google and 1 user for Yahoo.
I created a Bar chart to show the number of users per application, like below

[image]

its showing 4 users for Facebook, 4 for Google and 2 for Yahoo, basically it's just giving me a number of records.
How do I filter duplicates and just show correct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using count function, you need to count distinct instead.

Select your dimension in the column/row shelf, right click on it, and select option Measure Count (Distinct).

[image]